# Convert a PSD Photoshop file for Gimp

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, automation, actions, script

I'm looking for a script or any another solution to convert a PSD file for Gimp because our developpers use to work with Linux.

We've seen that some layers don't work, it is necessary to merge the masks, and to rasterize smart objects for example, or the PSD file cannot be opened by Gimp. I tried to create a Photoshop action, but I just can't select specific layers.

Does somebody know anything that might help to do this, as I am no developer myself?

Comment: I'm a developer that run into exactly this issue. These days few of my projects rely on Photoshop because we design directly on the web using living styleguides etc. But I still get the odd jobs that send send me PSD's, and I always have to ask them to rasterize and convert smart objects.

Have you found a solution to this problem?